# error " ; expected" ,sql statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
String l="UPDATE counselor SET firstName="qwe" WHERE id=1";
```

Could anyone tell me what's wrong with above statement,as q sql statement.
Netbeans displays as "; expected".
I can't understand why it isn't correct at least as a string.
Code is as follows.

```
String l="UPDATE counselor SET firstName="qwe" WHERE id=1";
Statement m=conn.createStatement();
ResultSet v=m.executeQuery(l);
```

Comment: It isn't correct because your string contains more double-quotes and Java doesn't know that they're meant to be part of the value and not the end of the string. As darijan points out you need single quotes for strings in SQL too - but that's the not the Java problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String l="UPDATE counselor SET firstName=\"qwe\" WHERE id=1";
```

If you want to put quotes within quotes you must use the escape sequence, \", on the interior quotes. To print the sentence. For example

```
She said "Hello!" to me.
```

you would write

```
System.out.println("She said \"Hello!\" to me.");
```

Comment: I did not downvote you, but I suggest not to use this MySQL quirk. The '-character is supported by all common database system to escape strings. But using the "-character to escape strings, is a MySQL quirk.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL, you should escape strings with `'`. So,

```
String l="UPDATE counselor SET firstName='qwe' WHERE id=1";
```

Comment: "In SQL, you *must* escape strings with `'`" - not true.

Comment: No, you haven't changed the meaning.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, many (most?) SQL database systems, use " to escape identifiers and ' to escape strings: `ERROR: column "qwe" does not exist; SQL Status:42703`. MySQL is an exception as it accepts " for strings. I suggest not to use this MySQL quirk in order to be able to support other database systems in the future more easily.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but what he wrote simply wasn't true now, was it?